# File Picker API for Evernote and OneDrive

Tags: javascript, evernote, filechooser, onedrive, filepicker

I'm developing an app for which a user can upload files from cloud domains like Dropbox, GoogleDrive, Box, Evernote and OneDrive.

I was able to find File Picker scripts for

Dropbox - https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js

GoogleDrive - https://gist.github.com/Daniel15/5994054 and

Box - http://developers.box.com/the-box-file-picker/#configurationoptions

Can anyone suggest me a similar file chooser script for Evernote and Onedrive???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a similar picker for OneDrive available at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219328.aspx